# Why does Sequel return only the first matching row?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have an SQLite3 database called sk.db with a table called Sked that displays a schedule of sports matches with a column date.  The code below gives me only the first matching row instead of all matching rows, of which there should be many. It doesnt matter what I use inside `where(...)` it only ever gives me the first matching row. If I use `schedule.all` it gives me the entire database but only the first matching row if I use `where`.

Where am I going wrong?

.rb

```
require 'date'
require 'sequel'
require 'sinatra'

DB = Sequel.connect("sqlite://sk.db")

class Sked < Sequel::Model
end

schedule = DB.from(:sked)

get '/' do
  @todaymatches = schedule.where(:date => Date.today)
  erb :games
end
```

.erb

```
 <h1>Games</h1>
 <p><%= @todaymatches.inspect %></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.where(...)` queries don't actually retrieve records, they return datasets that can be used to chain more queries for example:

```
my_posts = DB[:posts].where(:author => 'david').where(:topic => 'ruby') # no records are retrieved
```

If you want to actually retrieve the records, put an `all` at the end:

```
@todaymatches = schedule.where(:date => Date.today).all # records are retrieved
```

See: https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html

Answer (score 0):

This might be clunky, but I think it will do what you want.  Give it a whirl.

.rb

```
.
.
.
get '/' do
  @todaymatches = schedule.where(:date => Date.today)

  def print_today_matches
    @todaymatches.each { |x| puts x.inspect }
  end

  erb :games
end
```

.erb

```
<h1>Games</h1>
<p><%= print_today_matches %></p>
```

Or, alternatively:

.rb

```
.
.
.
get '/' do
  @todaymatches = schedule.where(:date => Date.today)
  erb :games
end
```

.erb

```
<h1>Games</h1>
<p><%= @todaymatches.each { |x| p x } %></p>
```